# Use jQuery to remove a <p> with an empty <span> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tubepress

I'm working on a Wordpress build using the Tubepress plug-in. This plug-in inserts an unwanted `<p>` above the video content. I'd like to remove this tag using jQuery.

Here's the code I'd like to remove:

```
<p><span id="more-76"></span></p>
```

The span id is auto-generated and will be different for each piece of content. This code is placed in the following div.

```
<div class="work1alt">
   <p><span id="more-76"></span></p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I realized about an hour after I posted this that the "MORE" tag within the editor was inserting this text at the top of the_content(). I no longer needed to use the "MORE" tag, so this solved the problem. I apologize for not posting this sooner, but appreciate the different approaches listed below. I'll now know what to do if I run into this problem in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('span:empty:only-child').parent('p').remove();
```

This will be extremely fast, but will not select `<span>`s with whitespace in them.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks! BTW, that's a selector, not a property.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.work1alt').find('p span:empty').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

The first if condition checks if there is no children or content I believe. The second checks if the span contains empty text and will return only text within the span, but not it's children.

Not as elegant and probably not as fast as slak's solution, but is very explicit.

```
 $('div.work1alt > p span').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).text()) === ""){
       $(this).parent().remove();
    }
 });
```

EDIT: forgot to put the '===""' in the ifs (doh!)

Comment: Only if the `<p>` elements have no other children.   (You can check their `text()`)

Answer (score -1):

depends on what else stands on your page. Maybe you should try [this](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) like that `$('p').remove();`

Comment: This doesn't help at all.  He's looking for a selector.